# Broadcasting when setting on a boolean slice of a DataFrame gives weird results

Tags: python, pandas, array-broadcasting

Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"AAA": [4, 5, 6, 7], "BBB": [10, 20, 30, 40], "CCC": [100, 50, -30, -50]}
)

df[[True, False, False, True]] = np.array([2,5]).reshape(2,1) 
df
   AAA  BBB  CCC
0    2    2    2
1    5   20   50
2    6   30  -30
3    5    5    5
```

This applies broadcasting to the dataframe and results in the first row containing solely the value 2 and the fourth row containing only the value 5. As I expected. Now, I just add a single column to the df and apply a similar transformation:

```
df["logic"] = 9

df[[True, False, False, True]] = np.array([3,7]).reshape(2,1)
```

Rather than delivering a first row containing only 3 and a last row containing only 7, I now get a

> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray

Can someone explain, why this is happening?

Comment: I have a replacement array with the same length. It is similar as the first example. The number of rows hasn't changed.

Comment: This is so weird that it could be worth you reporting it as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a shortcoming of how pandas checks the validity of the right-hand-side array and that in the idea of this check even `df[[True, False, False, True]] = np.array([2,5]).reshape(2,1)`  should fail.

A workaround would be to explicitly broadcast:

```
target = np.array([3, 7])

df[[True, False, False, True]] = np.repeat(target[:, None], df.shape[1], axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df[[True, False, False, True]] = np.broadcast_to(target[:,None], (2, df.shape[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks - but forgive me for saying: This is just crazy that it works in the first example and not in the second. I also think that it would be useful if one could rely on basic numpy-broadcasting rules (after all they are used in various functions of pandas) to work. If I understand your suggestion correct, then you say that I need to perform the broadcast manually ahead.

Comment: I fully agree, unless I missed something I would even think that this could be seen as a bug